# How do I get my simple model to open correctly in Adobe Dimension

Tags: export, vertices

I'm trying to get a model I've made into Adobe dimension. I've exported all different options, the closest to blender is exported as an obj. However, there's one part that is causing me grief. I've used a boolean in Blender and applied it to the model (so it's destructive) but it's filling in the hole in Dimension. When I look at it closer in [image]blender, the model has two pieces which I've tried to join with no success. I'm sure this must be a easy fix for someone who knows what they are doing (unlike me). Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try adding supporting geometry, vertices in the centers of the faces, so that a line between a corner to any other point to fill in a face wouldn't go outside the bounds of that face.

Comment: Looks like n-gons are supported differently in the other software. Try to limit yourself to quads and triangles when possible